# How to write into AudioTrack from JNI?

Tags: android

In my native code I'm receiving audio packets. I'm then sending them to Java to be played with `AudioTrack`. I experience audio stuttering though. I wonder if someone can explain to me a better way to play audio with `AudioTrack` than I currently do.

So, I do as follows:

1) Allocate a big `byte[]` array in Java and pass it and its size to JNI

2) When audio packet is ready in the native code I `memcpy` it to the beginning of that array

3) I then notify java by calling a Java callback from JNI passing audio size

4) I then do `AudioTrack.write` in Java passing that big byte array and the size from 3)

Can it be done somehow more efficient?

Comment: I would suggest try some sort of buffering technique so you can have a good chunk of data to play.

Comment: @JoxTraex Thank you. I would very much appreciate, if at all possible, some pseudocode or anything so I can better understand.

Comment: Why not create a couple of rotating arrays in Java that are passed down to the JNI.  That way your Native code always has a reference to these so you don't have to do a memcpy. Your native code can then fill a buffer and then move to the next.  Your Java code can then listen to the array until it gets filled up or the callback can notify Java which array to look at play.